# Display Error message if values already exist in Database

Tags: php

Firstly if i select "schoolbag & Soup" & click on "**save**" button , than values are saved in Database & **redirect** to **saveoutofstock.php** page. Thats fine....

[image]

Second time if i select same options - "schoolbag & Soup" , than it will not save in database [ because i executed this before : `ALTER TABLE outofstock ADD UNIQUE account_prod (name(90), type(90));` ]  , but still it redirect to saveoutofstock.php page. but instead of redirecting , i want to display error message as **name and type already exists**

**Form**

```
<form name="adduserforms" id="adduserforms" action="saveoutofstock.php" >
<select name="names" id="names" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
        <option value="A">>A</option>
        <option value="B">>B</option>
</select>

<select name="department" id="department" class="username">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="assign" value="Save" onclick="assignusers();"/>
```

**saveoutofstock.php**

```
<?php
$_SESSION['login_user'];

if(isset($_POST['edituser']) && $_POST['edituser']=="editUsers")
{
    if($_SESSION['login_user']=='admin')
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE outofstock set name='".$name."',type='".$type."' WHERE id=".$_POST['userId'];
    }   

    $redirectUrl="outofstocklist.php";
}

else if
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM outofstock WHERE names = '".$name."' AND department ='".$type."' ";
    echo "name and type already exists";
}
 else
{

$sql = "INSERT INTO outofstock (name,type) VALUES ('".$name."','".$type."')";
$redirectUrl="outofstocklist.php";
}

$result = $db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);

?>
```

Comment: You need a test after `else if`.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables into SQL.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for suggestion, but sorry i did't understood : `You need a test after else if`

Comment: Just like `if (something)` you need `else if (something)`.

Comment: This is basic PHP syntax, it's the same in almost all languages.

Comment: Let's see how you came up with this guy... `$db_handle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit and to rearrange your code something like below....

it is not tested...

```
<?php
$_SESSION['login_user'];

if(isset($_POST['edituser']) && $_POST['edituser']=="editUsers"){
    if($_SESSION['login_user']=='admin') {
       $sql = "UPDATE outofstock set name='".$name."',type='".$type."' WHERE id=".$_POST['userId'];
       $result = $db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
       $redirectUrl="outofstocklist.php";

    } else { 

    $sqlnumrow = "SELECT * FROM outofstock WHERE names = '".$name."' AND department ='".$type."' ";
    $numrow = $db_handle->count($sqlnumrow );// I don't know what function name is yours to check num rows
    if($numrow !=0){
    echo "name and type already exists";
    } else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO outofstock (name,type) VALUES ('".$name."','".$type."')";

    $result = $db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
   $redirectUrl="outofstocklist.php";
   }
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, i updated your code as here : https://pastebin.com/EsXtMFCp , but it gave internal server error.... please check & help me....

Comment: where you have defined $_POST['userId'] ??

Comment: i defined `$_POST['userId']` in  in form page  : `<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $_POST['userid'];?>"/>`

Comment: i did't used any numrows function,  please tell me what function  i need to use ?

Comment: ok..... here in https://pastebin.com/EsXtMFCp you have changed code with many else....may be that's why, it is giving internal server error....do u tried code in my answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179354/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-dr-j-manish).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a unique index on `(name, type)`, you'll get an error when you try to perform the `INSERT`. You should check for that error.

```
$result = $db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
if (!$result && mysqli_errno($db_handle) == 1022) {
    echo "name and type already exist";
}
```

`1022` is the MySQL error code for a duplicate key.

Get rid of this code block:

```
else if
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM outofstock WHERE names = '".$name."' AND department ='".$type."' ";
    echo "name and type already exists";
}
```

it's incorrect syntax because there's no condition after `if`. It also doesn't do anything useful, since it's echoing that the name and type already exists before you ever try to do the `INSERT` that gets the error.

Comment: I updated your code, but it did't displayed any error message , please check code here : https://pastebin.com/GiyAciwL

Comment: You're still missing a condition after `else if`. You should be getting a syntax error, and the code won't run at all.

Comment: Also, my code assumes that `$db_handle` is the connection returned by `mysqli_connect()`. If you're using your own wrapper class, you need to call the method that returns the mysqli connection object, and use that in `mysqli_errno()`.

Comment: i updated as you said, but still not display any error message : https://pastebin.com/kFLr0R1y

Comment: You didn't fix `mysqli_errno($db_handle)` to use the actual mysqli connection object.

Comment: I don't know your `DBController` class, so I don't know how you should fix it. It's your software, I expect you to know how to adapt the answer to it.

Comment: `$conn` is a private variable, so it can't be accessed from this code. You need to add a method `getConn()` that returns this, then use `$db_handle->getConn()->errno`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179350/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-barmar).

Comment: Sorry, I need to go to sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default action when submitting the form.

On your `assignusers()` function add this `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning

```
function assignusers(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of your code here
    ...
}
```

Comment: i added your code as here : https://pastebin.com/ug0jFhS2 , now its not allowing to save whatever values i select....

Comment: Add `e.preventDefault()` at the end of the function.

Comment: i got error in console : Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined